# Spring Cloud can't work with kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream, spring-kafka

We use spring cloud with stream Kafka, it running well, but can't visit the spring mvc Urls, it works fine if I remove the @EnableBinding(Sink.class).

It seems that @EnableBinding(Sink.class) affect the spring mvc functionality.

```
2018-01-11 15:54:19.218 [restartedMain] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - The configuration 'value.serializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2018-01-11 15:54:19.218 [restartedMain] WARN  org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig - The configuration 'key.serializer' was supplied but isn't a known config.
2018-01-11 15:54:19.219 [restartedMain] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka version : 0.10.1.1
2018-01-11 15:54:19.219 [restartedMain] INFO  org.apache.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser - Kafka commitId : f10ef2720b03b247
```

Comment: I am not sure what you're trying to say here or how the shared log snippet speaks to the problem you are describing. There is a great possibility of missconfiguration, yet without any relevant details it is impossible to answer or even speculate on what that may be.

Comment: The best way to help us to identify the problem is sharing a simple project on GitHub with the readme how to reproduce

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem 
In order for your application to be able to communicate with Kafka,  need to define an outbound stream to write messages to a Kafka topic, and an inbound stream to read messages from a Kafka topic.

Spring Cloud provides a convenient way to do this by simply creating an interface that defines a separate method for each stream.

It seems that your interface is not in Spring context
You should use the @Component annotation,